# How to run a powershell script passing a parameter to another script in a remote server?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read a json file which is like below

```
[
{ "STORE": "1", "LocationUUID": "ABC" },
{ "STORE": "2", "LocationUUID": "DEF" }
]
```

and then run a for loop for each store and pass the accompanying LocationUUID as a parameter to another PowerShell script, and run the script in Stores 1 and 2.

```
$storeLocationUUIDJSON = Get-Content '{my path here}'  -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$storeLocationUUIDJSON | Select-Object -Property STORE, LocationUUID |

ForEach-Object {
$computer = $_.STORE
$location = $_.LocationUUID
$filepath = 'test.ps1'
Write-Host "Started running the script on Store" + $computer + $location

try{
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -FilePath $filepath -LocationUUID $location
}
catch
{
Write-Host "Not successful on Store" + $computer
Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}
}
```

Test script to be run in Stores 1 and 2 is like below:

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $LocationUUID
)
Write-host $LocationUUID
New-Item 'T:\test.txt' -type file
```

Whenever I run this, I get the error
A parameter cannot be found that matches the parameter name 'LocationUUID'.

Can I get some help on this?

Comment: Use return : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3

Comment: What is the exact error? Note that the value `"ABC"` in the example is not a valid `Guid`: `& { param( [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [guid] $LocationUUID ) } 'ABC'` --> **`Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'LocationUUID'. Cannot convert value "ABC" to type "System.Guid". Error: "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)."`**

Comment: Ah yes. I have removed the guid and put ABC just for this question. The actual content was a Guid. Mathias' answer works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining that `Invoke-Command` doesn't have a `LocationUUID` parameter.

Don't use `Invoke-Command` to run code locally, use the invocation operator `&` instead:

```
& $filepath -LocationUUID $location
```

Comment: Hi, yes it works in my local. But what if I want to run the script from a server, connecting to each store servers? @Mathias R. Jessen